# How to disable image map on a slider on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, dictionary

I'm working on a site that features an image slider with image maps on each image. It works fine but gets messed up on mobile versions. I'm wondering if there's any way to create a new image map when viewed on phone or even to disable the image map.

Here's my html below. I've tried using `display:none` in the `@media` only screen parts of the css and it didn't work. I've also used mattstows responsive image map plugin and that didn't work either.

```
<div class="rslides_container">
    <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
    
        <li><img src="images/1.png" usemap="#map1"/>
                <map name="map1">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="10,49,454,323" href=""  title="" />
                    <area shape="rect" coords="509,48,960,322" href="" title=""/>
                    <area shape="rect" coords="298, 335, 433, 359" href="" title=""/>
                    <area shape="rect" coords="803, 333, 938, 356" href="" title=""/>
                </map>
        
        

        </li>
        
        <li><img src="images/2.png" usemap="#map1"/>
                <map name="map1">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="10,49,454,323" href=""  title="" />
                    <area shape="rect" coords="509,48,960,322" href="" title=""/>
                    <area shape="rect" coords="298, 335, 433, 359" href="" title=""/>
                    <area shape="rect" coords="803, 333, 938, 356" href="" title=""/>
                </map>
        
        </li>
        
        <li><img src="images/3.png" usemap="#map1"/>
                <map name="map1">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="10,49,454,323" href=""  title="" />
                    <area shape="rect" coords="509,48,960,322" href="" title=""/>
                    <area shape="rect" coords="298, 335, 433, 359" href="" title=""/>
                    <area shape="rect" coords="803, 333, 938, 356" href="" title=""/>
                </map>
        
        </li>
        
    </ul>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }   

.rslides li {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }


.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }

 .rslides {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.rslides_container {

  position: relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply detect if the user is using a mobile browser and then remove all the `<map>` tags.

```
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4)))
$('map').remove();
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply! where do i paste this code? and do i need to add script tags

Comment: i added it to the page in script tags and it works!! the image map is removed! thank you!